# jquery or php or something else. Show full phone number only when user clicks on link

Tags: php, jquery

Have php `$phone_number=1234567;`

On page load like

```
<span id="span_phone_number">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars( substr_replace( $phone_number, "...", -3 ), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");?>
</span>
<span id="show_phone_number">Show</span>
```

First idea to use jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '#show_phone_number', function(){
$("#span_phone_number").html( '<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $phone_number, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>' );
});
```

But i can see full phone number in View source.

`$phone_number` i get from mysql.

Next idea is with `$.post` send `id` to external `php` file, in that file connect to mysql and get full phone number. But it is waste of resources.

Is it possible in less resource consuming way at page load hide full phone number in view source and show full phone number only on click?

Next idea:

1. Create some number (?random)
2. To ajax send the created number and phone number without 3 last digits
3. In external php based on created number and part of phone number create correct phone number
   But how? What would be idea how to get 3 necessary digits based on some random number?

Or may be exists something simpler?

May aim is to prevent parse phone numbers by bots from html source.

Found this http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/85597-converting-a-number-to-another-number-encrypt-decrypt/?p=436824

```
$original = 123;
$secure = rand(100,999).base64_encode($original);
$unsecure = substr($secure,3);
$unsecure = base64_decode($unsecure);
echo $unsecure; // will display 123
```

Seems it works. But at the moment do not understand how and why it works...

Comment: You could reverse the phone number in the PHP, output it the browser, and then have a JS function that orders it correctly on click.

Comment: If i reverse and potential bad person knows it, the person can parse reversed phone number and convert to correct. Better would be to create something random and based on the something random change phone number and on click change to correct number. But how?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to hide it from source code, you may try to save it inside session. For example:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['phoneNumber'] = '123456789';

    echo $_SESSION['phoneNumber'];
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean in external php take phone number based on session? It may be idea.... Somewhere read that it is not good to have many sessions... Or am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
<?php
$phonenumber = (int)strrev('123');
$random = (int)time();
$encrypt = ($phonenumber + $random);
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="clickme">Click to see Phone</a>
<div style="display:none;" id="displayphone"><?php echo $encrypt?></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        var phonenumber = $('#displayphone').html() - <?php echo $random;?>;
        var realphonenumber = phonenumber.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
        $("#displayphone").slideDown().html(realphonenumber);
    });
</script>
```